# Why does nested loop cause a Run Time Error 13?

Tags: excel, vba

I've written a macro that structures a lot of data and saving me for manual punching of numbers etc. The macro is written in stages were each part have been tested isolated and then integrated in loops or to the main code it self - this way each piece of code is tested so it functions accordingly to my intentions.

The goal for this part of code is to cycle through each row in the sheet, if the value of column 9, row I is different from the column 9, row I-1, then it will insert a new row (sum row). This action will be preformed in each worksheet, hence nested loop. When I wrote this macro isolated, without nesting loops, it functioned well.

*Edit:* To clearify, the code insert a row if and only if `Cells(I, PrGr) = Cells(I - 1, PrGr)` are unequal. Therefore I ask if they are the same, if they are so, do nothing - else, insert a row (i.e. `Cells(I, PrGr) = Cells(I - 1, PrGr)` are not equal.)

Running it in a nested loop causes a *Run Time Error 13, type mismatch* on the line with "*If Cells(I, PrGr) = Cells(I - 1, PrGr) Then*". In debugger, when I force it to continue, it does what it is supposed to do - creating the sum rows for in every sheet. This happens regardless of which sheet I set as the starting sheet.

I've tried to change the logic of the loop by testing with *For Each ws In This..* and with the logic I have now *For J = 1 to WS_ant*. Both causes the error. I also searched around for clues, but non has come up with any solution appropriate for this problem.

Does someone have a clue to what is happening here, and how to fix it?

The code:

```
Sub OI_SJ()

'Selects the first sheet
Sheets(1).Activate

'Loop through sheets
Dim J As Integer
Dim WS_ant As Integer

Dim starting_ws As Worksheet
Set starting_ws = ActiveSheet 'remember which worksheet is active in the beginning
WS_ant = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

    For J = 1 To WS_ant
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(J).Activate

        'If sheet = GRL, then terminate
        If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(J).Name = "LL - Sv" Or ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(J).Name = "RM - Sv" Then

            'do something later

            ElseIf ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(J).Name = "GRL" Then GoTo Term5

            Else
                Dim I As Integer
                Dim PrGr As Long
                PrGr = 9

                Set aktivtark = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(J)

                With aktivtark
                    sistekolonne = aktivtark.Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
                    sisterad = aktivtark.Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
                End With

                Application.CutCopyMode = False
                Application.ScreenUpdating = False

                With aktivtark.Range("A6", Cells(sisterad, sistekolonne))
                    .RowHeight = 15

                End With
                Rows(1).RowHeight = 24

                For I = 6 To sisterad + 153

                If Cells(I, PrGr) = Cells(I - 1, PrGr) Then
                    ElseIf Cells(I, PrGr) = "PrGr" Then
                    Else
                        Rows(I).EntireRow.Insert
                        Cells(I, 12) = "SUM " & Cells(I - 1, PrGr).Value
                        Cells(I, 33).Formula = "=SUMIF(R7C9:R1500C9,MID(RC12,5,255),R7C:R1500C)"
                        Cells(I, 34).Formula = "=SUMIF(R7C9:R1500C9,MID(RC12,5,255),R7C:R1500C)"
                        Cells(I, 35).Formula = "=SUMIF(R7C9:R1500C9,MID(RC12,5,255),R7C:R1500C)"
                        Cells(I, 36).Formula = "=SUMIF(R7C9:R1500C9,MID(RC12,5,255),R7C:R1500C)"
                        Cells(I, 37).Formula = "=SUMIF(R7C9:R1500C9,MID(RC12,5,255),R7C:R1500C)"
                        Cells(I, 38).Formula = "=SUMIF(R7C9:R1500C9,MID(RC12,5,255),R7C:R1500C)"
                        Cells(I, 39).Formula = "=SUMIF(R7C9:R1500C9,MID(RC12,5,255),R7C:R1500C)"
                        Cells(I, 40).Formula = "=SUMIF(R7C9:R1500C9,MID(RC12,5,255),R7C:R1500C)"
                        Cells(I, 41).Formula = "=SUMIF(R7C9:R1500C9,MID(RC12,5,255),R7C:R1500C)"
                        Cells(I, 42).Formula = "=SUMIF(R7C9:R1500C9,MID(RC12,5,255),R7C:R1500C)"
                        Cells(I, 43).Formula = "=SUMIF(R7C9:R1500C9,MID(RC12,5,255),R7C:R1500C)"
                        Cells(I, 44).Formula = "=SUMIF(R7C9:R1500C9,MID(RC12,5,255),R7C:R1500C)"
                        Rows(I).RowHeight = 17.25
                        I = I + 1
                End If

            Next

            Application.CutCopyMode = True
            Application.ScreenUpdating = True

        End If

Cycle:
    Next

Term5:
starting_ws.Activate 'activate the worksheet that was originally active

End Sub
```

Comment: Which type of values you have in those cells? You may try to use `If Cells(I, PrGr).Value = Cells(I - 1, PrGr).Value Then`

Comment: `Cells(I, PrGr) = Cells(I - 1, PrGr)` refers to the `ActiveSheet` which is probably **not** what you want to check. Also, I'm not quite following your logic of `If` > `ElseIf` > `Else` in that particular part of your code....You seem to want to do nothing when `Cells(I, PrGr) = Cells(I - 1, PrGr)` would be `TRUE`

Comment: `Rows(1).RowHeight = 24` to be replaced with `aktivtark.Rows(1).RowHeight = 24`, `Cells(...` with `aktivtark.Cells(...` and so on... When you run each simple piece of code you did it on the ActiveSheet. Now, it is mandatory to define the page where it must work! If you have doubts it is good to run your code line by line using F8 and see the real variable data which the code processes.

Answer (score 0):

With the insight from Vitaliy Prushak's post, I've changed that bit of code from `If Cells(I, PrGr) = Cells(I - 1, PrGr) Then` to  `If Cells(I, PrGr).Text = Cells(I - 1, PrGr).Text Then`, since the cells contain text. This pushed the problem further down in the code, but it was solved with the same solution.

The macro now runs as it should, thanks for the help.